# Setting the SameSite Attribute on the JSESSIONID cookie using Apache config

Tags: apache, cookies, session-cookies, httpd.conf, samesite

I have a Apache 2.4 and Tomcat 9 setup. I need to set the SameSite attribute on the JSESSIONID cookie.

Using Fiddler, I can see that the cookies is set as follows when I login;

`Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=XXXXXXXXXXX; Path=/prod1; Secure; HttpOnly`

I also want to set the SameSite Attribute on the cookie using Apache. I have the following in vhost conf, but this doesn't seem to work.

`Header always edit* Set-Cookie "^(JSESSIONID.*)$" $1;SameSite=Lax`

I know that the Header directive works as I have set other attributes (not on cookies) just above this line.
However, this doesn't seem to work. I've tried a few variations, but can't seem to get this working.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With some more trial and error I found that removing the always condition works and the JSESIONID cookie has the SameSite Attribute.

Looking at the Apache mod_headers documentation, the reason is not clear. The documentation says

> always is not a superset of onsuccess with respect to existing headers

However, doesn't give much details.
Ref: [Apache Module mod_headers](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_headers.html)

Comment: I think i wrote that warning in the manual, forgot it, and re-learned it in your answer while looking at SameSite questions.    I will look at improving the confusing wording in the manual.

Comment: The latest docs are helpful, in that they explain that `always` and `onsuccess` are the names of two tables of headers and that the one you're trying to edit could be in either of them.  I found it helpful to just duplicate my `Header edit` line, so I have `Header always edit` and `Header onsuccess edit`.